# Cypher query freezes on specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running this query:

```
MATCH (n1:Word{word: '"+word1+"'})-[r*]-(n2:Word) 
WHERE (n2.word <> n1.word) AND (n2.pos CONTAINS 'NN') 
RETURN DISTINCT(n2)
```

for different values of `word1` and it runs perfectly for dozens of words, but when it comes to the word `'method'` the server just doesn't responds. I've checked all the nodes with this value on the `property.word` and nothing seems to be different than other nodes.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that in the specific case of this word there was a loop that fitted the query and because of `[r*]` was allowing the query to search for paths of infinite length, result: **deadlock**.

By fixing a max path size (e.g.`[r*0..10]`) my problem was solved.

Hope this helps other users (: